# RegEx replace only occurrences outside of <h> html tags

Tags: html, regex, vba, regex-negation, regexp-replace

I would like to regex replace **Plus** in the below text, but only when it's **not** wrapped in a header tag:

```html
<h4 class="Somethingsomething" id="something">Plus plan</h4>The <b>Plus</b> plan starts at $14 per person per month and comes with everything from Basic.
```

In the above I would like to replace the second "Plus" but not the first.

My regex attempt so far is:

```
(?!<h\d*>)\bPlus\b(?!<\\h>)
```

Meaning:

1. Do not capture the following if in a <h + 1 digit and 0 or more characters and end an closing <\h>
2. Capture only if the group "Plus" is surrounded by spaces or white space

However - this captures both occurrences. Can someone point out my mistake and correct this?
[image]

I want to use this in VBA but should be a general regex question, as far as I understand.

[Somewhat related but not addressing my problem in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301667/regex-to-replace-text-only-when-occurs-outside-of-two-strings)

[Not relevant, as not RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326919/only-replace-words-outside-of-html-tags)

Comment: A regex in VBA is certainly not a general regex question. Just a non-POSIX regex is under consideration here.

Comment: Try `\bPlus\b(?![^>]*<\/h\d+>)`, see https://regex101.com/r/Dkkn2y/2. Or, `\bPlus\b(?=<\/b>)`, see https://regex101.com/r/Dkkn2y/3. Are you replacing or extracting the matches? What are you trying to achieve? It would also help if you share your current VBA code.

Comment: Replacing is the goal. I need to insert our variable to inter-link pages. So the replaced value should be: `<h4 class="Somethingsomething" id="something">Plus plan</h4>The <b>{{Provider_Link 'Plus', 33}}</b> plan starts at $14 per person per month and comes with everything from Basic.`

Comment: Ok, then `\bPlus\b(?![^>]*<\/h\d+>)` is a kind of a workaround that might work for you. The replacement would be `{{Provider_Link '$&', 33}}`. See https://regex101.com/r/Dkkn2y/4

Comment: Smart - you're simply ignoring the beginning and focus on the closing header tag, correct? Assuming that the header tag needs to be closed to be valid html and thus be present.

Comment: Yes, that is a "trick" and assumes the open tag exists and the code is valid HTML code. Also, it assumes there are no nested tags.

Comment: Hm, nope, that still seems to work (if I understand correctly what you mean by nested tags: `<h4 class="Somethingsomething" id="something">Plus plan</h4><p>The <b>Plus</b> plan starts at $14 per person per month and comes with everything from Basic.</p>` works: https://imgur.com/a/rt1gGLY

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You might be able to get this to work in certain cases if your HTML always follows a known pattern, but in general the problem can't be solved with regex and needs an HTML parser. See this answer (from the question @HackSlash linked to): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/896841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\bPlus\b(?![^>]*<\/h\d+>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dkkn2y/4). To use the match inside the replacement pattern, use the `$&` backreference in your VBA code.

*Details*:

- `\bPlus\b` - a whole word `Plus`
- `(?![^>]*<\/h\d+>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
  - `<\/h` - `</h` string
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `>` - a `>` char.